# Android JPEG scaling library?

Tags: android, jpeg

I'm well familiar with Bitmaps in android and their limitations when it comes to memory utilization for high res. images.

What I'm looking for is an alternative library (based on java/c, ported to android) that can do jpeg-to-jpeg conversions so that I can scale high res images e.g. 12MP to 8MP. Such things are not possible using [Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[libvips](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=Libvips) could potentially be a good candidate as it is known to be *the fastest image processing library tested and uses the smallest amount of memory* and it [open files in a smart way](http://libvips.blogspot.fr/2012/06/how-libvips-opens-file.html). That being said:

- it does not provide a JNI wrapper out-of-the box - you should make sure the lib can be ported to Android and write your own wrapper,
- you will have to include support for JPEG compression/decompression - I would say that [libjpeg-turbo](http://libjpeg-turbo.virtualgl.org/) could be a good candidate as it clearly supports the ARM architecture and **has been [ported to Android](http://lists.linaro.org/pipermail/linaro-dev/2011-September/007219.html)**

You could also check if libjpeg-turbo only is sufficient as it includes the ability to scale down images during decompression.

Comment: ported to android link is broken it seems